# windows 10: How can I use the "third monitor only" (without unpluging the second monitor)?

Tags: windows, windows-10, multiple-monitors

My laptop is connected to 2 external monitors (which makes 3 monitors with laptop inbuilt monitor).  Windows 10 only offers "second screen only" but no "third screen only" option. Which means that to use one of the 2 external monitors, I need to unplug the other.

I know the monitors are well detected because I can (only) "extend" the desktop to both monitors. So I could work with 3 monitors on "extend" mode, but that's not what I'm looking for.

**How can I use the "third monitor only" without unplugging the second monitor?** (I need to unplug it several time per day which might damage the connections)

Comment: Your question isn’t clear.

Comment: @Ramhound what point you don't understand?

Comment: On a monitor that you unplug, can you ensure it is physically OFF?  There is sometimes a front button to turn the monitor off. If that does not work, you will need to unplug the monitor from the card.

Comment: @John 56 I'm not sure to understand your idea behind. But when the monitors are connected they are well connected (otherwise they wouldn't "extend" the desktop), and yes when I unplugged monitor2 to use the monitor3, I really unplug it, and monitor3 works as expected (but it isn't the point).

Comment: @John Monitors are usually designed to still be detected despite being turned off. Weird, but hey.

Comment: Many laptops may provide 2 or more monitor ports (ex: VGA & HDMI) however that doesn't mean it can support three screens (laptop & 2 external monitors) at the same time. Please provide your laptop brand, model, & processor for us to confirm

Comment: That is precisely why I suggested trying the OFF button. I know that some monitors will be detected when OFF (I have one) and if that is the case then it needs to be unplugged from the card.

Comment: @gregg, the laptop support 2 (at least) 3 monitors: as I said, windows can "extend" the desktop on both monitor2 and monitor3 (on the same time). But it isn't the point.

Comment: When they are both plugged in, do they show up in Device Manager?  Try right-click on one of them in Device Manager and "Disable".

Comment: I have the very same question. As I have an AMD CPU with integrated Radeon graphics, I cannot use the Intel tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following these  steps seems to work

[image]

I discovered I could even add some hotkey to switch (and shut down) the monitors. [image]

*edit: there is a little bug. If by mistake, I switch to a monitor that isn't powered, there are 2 problems:

1. it doesn't show as "second screen only" but as "extend"
2. it detects the wrong resolution size (it takes the size of the other external monitor. And changing its resolution on windows doesn't work (option grayed out), and changing it using the Intel's "graphic and media control panel" throw an error: intel graphic input signal out of range" ). I need to plug in and out the VGA connector to get it recognized.*

Answer (score 1):

In case you may be working with windows 11 now you can do the following:

1- Make sure you are in 2nd display-only mode, then go to display settings (by right-clicking on the home screen or just by pulling up settings).

2- Click the monitor that is labeled as 2.

3- In the section at the top that allows for display adjustment, click the drop-down menu directly right of identity, then select disconnect this display.

4- It will bring a pop-up menu asking if you want to keep the changes, click "Keep changes".

This should still keep it connected for when you change to extend or other monitor options but then disconnect it when you switch to 2nd display.

Apologies if anything is unclear. Not sure if this is plausible on windows 10.